# Error in implementing full text search in flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm storing my agent data in firestore. But as I want search implementation in my code. I want to search the user by its city. So i'm trying to store search index of the city. Even if I type a single alphabet for the search query I should get the most appropriate result from the firestore.
How to use upload data function with my current code of adding data to firestore. I only want to use uploadData function with my city. So i can search that agent using city.
I have added city controller to uploadData function on calling it. But i'm not calling it the right way. As, it displays error.

**The error i got**

```
I/flutter (25254): ...skipping image upload
E/flutter (25254): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
E/flutter (25254): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:166:60)
E/flutter (25254): #1      _AgentSignUpState.uploadData (package:signup/agentSignup.dart:115:29)
E/flutter (25254): #2      _AgentSignUpState._showName.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:signup/agentSignup.dart:513:85)
E/flutter (25254): #3      _AgentSignUpState._showName.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:signup/agentSignup.dart:502:56)
E/flutter (25254): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:992:19)
E/flutter (25254): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1098:38)
E/flutter (25254): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:184:24)
E/flutter (25254): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:524:11)
E/flutter (25254): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:284:5)
E/flutter (25254): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:256:7)
E/flutter (25254): #10     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:158:27)
E/flutter (25254): #11     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:224:20)
E/flutter (25254): #12     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200:22)
E/flutter (25254): #13     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:7)
E/flutter (25254): #14     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:104:7)
E/flutter (25254): #15     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:88:7)
E/flutter (25254): #16     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (25254): #17     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (25254): #18     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (25254): #19     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267:10)
E/flutter (25254): #20     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176:5)
E/flutter (25254):
```

**My code**

```
uploadData(String name)async
{
  List<String> splitList = name.split(' ');
  List<String> indexList = [];
  for(int i=0; i<splitList[i].length; i++)
    {
      for(int j=0;j<splitList[i].length+i; j++)
        {
          indexList.add(splitList[i].substring(0,j).toLowerCase());
        }
    }
  Firestore.instance.collection('agentRequest').add({'city':name,'searchIndex':indexList});
  }
```

My Textfield and where i'm calling my function for storing my data in firestore.

```
         Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                    validator: ValidateLocation,
                                    controller: _location,
//                onSaved: (String val) {
//                  Location = val;
//                },
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    autofocus: false,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                                          Icons.add_location,
                                          color: Colors.grey[800],
                                        ),
                                        labelText: 'Enter Your Address:'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                    validator: ValidateLocation,
                                    controller: _city,
//                onSaved: (String val) {
//                  Location = val;
//                },
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    autofocus: false,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                                          Icons.add_location,
                                          color: Colors.grey[800],
                                        ),
                                        labelText: 'Enter City Name:'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                    validator: validateMobile,
                                    controller: _phoneController,
//                onSaved: (String val) {
//                  PhoneNumber = val;
//                },
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    autofocus: false,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                                          Icons.dialer_sip,
                                          color: Colors.grey[800],
                                        ),
                                        labelText: 'Enter Number:'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  //padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50, bottom: 10),
                                  //color: Colors.grey[200],
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        TextFormField(
                                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                          validator: ValidateDescp,
                                          controller: _description,
//                      onSaved: (String val) {
//                        Description = val;
//                      },
                                          maxLines: 4,
                                          autofocus: false,
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                              prefixIcon: Icon(
                                                Icons.description,
                                                color: Colors.grey[800],
                                              ),
                                              labelText: 'Your Introduction:'),
                                          //textAlign: TextAlign,
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),
                                          width: 165,
                                          child: FlatButton(
                                            disabledColor: Colors.grey[800],
                                            onPressed: () async {

                                              _validate = true;
                                              agent.Name = _firstName.text;
                                              agent.phoneNumber=_phoneController.text;
                                              agent.age= _age.text;
                                              agent.description=_description.text;
                                              agent.address = _location.text;
                                              agent.city=_city.text;
                                              agent.uid = user.uid;
                                              if (_sendToServer()) {
                                                AgentDatabase().ApplyForAgent(agent);
                                                uploadData(_city.text);
                                                /*_firestore.collection("agentRequest").document(
                                                    firebaseUser.uid).setData({
                                                  "displayName": _firstName.text,
                                                  "age": _age.text,
                                                  'phoneNumber': _phoneController.text,
                                                  "address": _location.text,
                                                  "description": _description.text,
                                                                 });*/
                                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                                _validate = false;
                                                return true;
                                              }

                                              Navigator.pop(context);
```

My agent database class.

```
class AgentDatabase{
  final Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;

  Future<String> ApplyForAgent(AgentUser user) async {
    String retVal = 'error';
    try {
      await _firestore.collection('agentRequest').document(user.uid).setData({
        'displayName': user.Name,
        'Address': user.address,
        'description': user.description,
        'phoneNumber': user.phoneNumber,
        'city':user.city,
        'uid': user.uid,
        'User Type': "user",
        //    'accountCreated' : Timestamp.now(),

      });

      retVal='Success';
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return retVal;
  }
```

Comment: "As, it displays error." Please edit your question to include the exact error message and stack trace you get.

Comment: what's the value of the `index` variable?, I don't find where it's being filled